# display message when regex does not match (task failed)

Tags: regex, ansible, yaml

I want to display a message if the task failed. This is that I currently have. I can't seem to store the stdout

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    regexp: '(?i)^\s*PASS_MAX_DAYS\s+[0-9]+\s*$'
    pass_max_days: "{{ out.stdout_lines|
                       select('match', regexp)|first|split|last }}"
  tasks:
    - command: cat /tmp/login.defs
      register: out
    - debug:
        var: pass_max_days

    - debug:
        msg: Less than 90 days
      when: pass_max_days|int < 90
    - debug:
        msg: Exactly 90 days
      when: pass_max_days|int == 90
    - debug:
        msg: More than 90 days
      when: pass_max_days|int > 90
    - debug:
        msg: Does not match!
      when: pass_max_days.rc != 0
```

Comment: The Center for Internet Security (CIS) control for `PASS_MAX_DAYS` sources `/etc/login.defs` not `/tmp/...`, see in example [How to set user password expirations on Linux](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/password-expiration-date-linux).

Answer (score 1):

Use [block & rescue](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html#handling-errors-with-blocks).
The task under rescue will be executed, only if a task in the block fails.

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    regexp: '(?i)^\s*PASS_MAX_DAYS\s+[0-9]+\s*$'
    pass_max_days: "{{ out.stdout_lines|
                       select('match', regexp)|first|split|last }}"
  tasks:
  - block:
     - name: cat the file
       command: cat /etc/login.defs
       register: out

     - name: line search
       debug:
        var: pass_max_days

     - name: line check
       debug:
         msg: "{% if pass_max_days|int < 90 %}Less than 90 days{% elif pass_max_days|int == 90 %}Exactly 90 days{% elif pass_max_days|int > 90 %}More than 90 days{% endif %}"

    rescue:
      - name: Failure message
        debug:
          msg: "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
```

Success:

```yaml
TASK [cat the file] *************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [line search] **************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "pass_max_days": "99999"
}

TASK [line check] ***************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "More than 90 days"
}
```

Failure:

```yaml
TASK [cat the file] *************************************

TASK [line search] **************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "pass_max_days": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}

TASK [line check] ***************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: {{ out.stdout_lines| select('match', regexp)|first|split|last }}: Unable to look up a name or access an attribute in template string ({{ out.stdout_lines| select('match', regexp)|first|split|last }}).\nMake sure your variable name does not contain invalid characters like '-': descriptor 'split' for 'str' objects doesn't apply to a 'AnsibleUndefined' object\n\nThe error appears to be in '/root/ansible-test/max.yml': line 16, column 8, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n     - name: line check\n       ^ here\n"}

TASK [Failure message] *********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}
```

If you want the tasks in block not to be executed at failure, use [check_mode](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html#attributes) in lineinfile module to check if the line exists.
Register an output for the task, which will have the attribute `changed` as true, if the line is found, but it will not make any changes to the file.

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    regexp: '(?i)^\s*PASS_MAX_DAYS\s+[0-9]+\s*$'
    pass_max_days: "{{ out.stdout_lines | select('match', regexp)|first|split|last }}"
  tasks:
  - name: Check if line exists
    lineinfile:
      name: /etc/login.defs
      regexp: "{{ regexp }}"
      line: ""
      state: present
    check_mode: yes
    register: check

  - name: Failure message
    debug:
      msg: "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
    when: check is not changed

  - block:
      - name: cat the file
        command: cat /etc/login.defs
        register: out

      - name: line check
        debug:
          msg: "{% if pass_max_days|int < 90 %}Less than 90 days{% elif pass_max_days|int == 90 %}Exactly 90 days{% elif pass_max_days|int > 90 %}More than 90 days{% endif %}"
    when: check is changed
```